# Match values between 2 sheets on excel, if match found, update cell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using openpyxl to manipulate some spreadsheets.  I have this code to match values between two sheets on Excel, if the values match it updates a cell in that row:

```
for cell in ws1['a']:  
    for num in ws4['a']:
        if cell.value == num.value:
            ws1.cell(row=cell.row, column=23).value = ws4.cell(row=num.row, column=9).value
```

There are 10000 rows of data on each sheet.  This task takes a couple minutes to complete.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code? I don't see anything particularly slow about this.

Comment: I have no issue with the speed of the rest of the code. Just wondering if there is a faster method. As this checks up to 10000 values against 1 before checking the next.

Comment: How do you know this is the slow part? Can you provide the wrapper and maybe some test cases for this code? (i.e. examples for `ws1` and `wss4).

Comment: Column A contains 10000 values of 10 digit numbers in both ws1 and ws4.  I know this is the slow part because, for each task in the code I have a print statement above the task.  This one says print('matching...') and lasts a couple of minutes.  Quicker tasks printing statements last for 20 seconds at most.  I'm sure there must be more sound ways to test the speed but I'm very new.

Comment: Do all 10000 cells have values? If not then you could skip empty cells

Comment: Yes they all have values.